# How to insert data from a json-object to a database

Tags: php, sql, json

I'm pretty new to json, but I'm trying to insert some data from json into a database table. I keep getting some errors:
Notice: Undefined index: subject
Notice: Undefined index: message

```
<?php
$jsondata = '{
  "p1" : [
{
"subject": "Something",
"message": "Something"
},
{
"subject": "Something111",
"message": "Something11"
}
]
}';

$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$p1 = $data['p1'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO 
        table(subject,
        message)
        VALUES('".$p1['subject]."', '".$p1['message]."'");
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

?>
```

Comment: $p1 is multidimensional array so use foreach loop\

Comment: So add up everything mentioned here, get a decent editor like netbeans or eclipse and you would have solved most of them before posting this question ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is many mistakes in your code.

**1.$p1 is multidimensional array your were treating as an array**

**2.You have forget comma(') before ] in query**

**3.You have close " at wrong place  in query it should be at last after values bracket.**

Use this code

```
$jsondata = '{
  "p1" : [
{
"subject": "Something",
"message": "Something"
},
{
"subject": "Something111",
"message": "Something11"
}
]
}';

$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$p1 = $data['p1'];
foreach($p1 as $val)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table(subject,message) VALUES('".$val['subject']."', '".$val['message']."')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

$p1 is an **array** of objects e.g.: {"subject":"xxxx", "message":"yyy"};

Thus, you have to **loop** $p1 and do the db insert

```
foreach ($p1 as $obj){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO 
    table(subject,
    message)
    VALUES('".$obj['subject]."', '".obj['message]."'");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is multidimension array in $p1
If you want to inset first row you can use this.Otherwise you need to use foreach

$sql = "INSERT INTO 
        table(subject,
        message)
        VALUES('".$p1[0]['subject']."', '".$p1[0]['message']."')";

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach loop will do the job but as it is an object you need to access it using the -> operator.


    <?php
    $jsondata = '{
    "p1" : [
    {
    "subject": "Something",
    "message": "Something"
    },
    {
    "subject": "Something111",
    "message": "Something11"
    }
    ]
    }';
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    $p1 = $data['p1'];
    foreach ($p1 as $object){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO  table(subject,message) VALUES ('".$object->subject."','".$object->message."'");
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    }
    ?>


I hope this helps you
```